# Impact of the location of the aircraft propeller on yawing moment

Tags: aerodynamics, aircraft

we know that the effect of P-factor on puller propellers is the yawing moment in the opposite direcrion.
i mean if we had a load(thrust or lift) on the right side of propeller , then airplane will yaw to the left.

now my question is : what about pusher propellers? is it the same scenario or the direction of load and resulting yaw is the same? i mean in pusher propellers the right load causes right yaw?

what about pitch motion?

Comment: Please elaborate more, for those (most) of us who are unfamiliar with P-factor and the effect you describe.

Comment: The only difference between a pusher and a puller propeller is which end of the crankshaft it is mounted on.